# Failed to push selection: Read-only file system

Tags: android

I am trying to push my video in SD Card but its showing error in console failed to push selection, please help me this problem.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/), and [How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html).

Answer (score 2):

In commmand

1. Write: `cd :/>C:\android\android-sdk-windows\platform-tools` (or where ever adb.exe is located.if adb.exe is not present in sdk,download it saperately)
2. Write: `adb remount`

not solved? see https://stackoverflow.com/a/14293973/1190809

Answer (score 0):

Just go C: -> Documents and Settings -> then go to ur workspace folder name -> Local Settings -> Application Data -> Android -> android-sdk -> platform-tools -> adb
Run this adb.exe.

Comment: This solution is Windows-based. You should at least give that hint to your answer or show solutions for other OS's.