# Eclipse console shows:'Failed to push selection: Read-only file system'when i try to push a file

Tags: android, eclipse, mobile, sd-card

I am trying to push a file to the SD Card but its showing error in console 'failed to push selection: Read-only file system'.I am using DDMS perspective in Eclipse.I generated sdcard using mksdcard command.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Just go to

`C:\Documents and Settings\<adminstrator>\.android\avd`

take `'properties'` of your avd folder (there is a folder for each of the avd's)

uncheck `'Read only'` -> OK

This was the only thing that worked for me.

P.S: Some of these folders might be hidden.

Comment: I don't have the properties file

Comment: It's not properties file, It's Right Click on avd Folder-> Properties -> uncheck Read Only. Simple!

Answer (score 13):

On the `Terminal` or `Command-Prompt`, write these( ***for me its command prompt*** ):

- `adb shell`(Opens the device shell. you'll see a `#`)
- `su`(get the root permission, if necessary)
- `mount -o rw,remount rootfs /`(remount the root file system.)
- `chmod 777 /mnt/sdcard` (change the permission of the sdcard to rwe.)
- `exit`

If it doesn't work, try to push the file from the same shell using `adb push` .
Hope this help.

Comment: The chmod command made the difference for me with an oDroid.  Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

You need to give SDCard support to your AVD and mount the SDCard.

First go to 'AVD Manager and select your AVD then Click on Edit and in the Hardware add SDCard Support'.

Please check [**this link**](http://daraizetechnologies.blogspot.in/2011/06/how-to-mount-sdcard-in-android-emulator.html) for complete detailed step to achieve SDCard support and mounting.

You can also give a try to this command in CMD, this will remount your SDCard.

```
c:\android-sdk\platform-tools\>adb remount
```

Comment: There is no `abd remount` command in this list. There is `adb remount' command. Also i've seen another places this 'abd'. Or, is it correct?

Answer (score 5):

I was also facing same issue :

Failed to push selection: Read-only file system

In computers with higher configuration(beyond Windows XP)
settings like ---> C:\Documents and Settings\.android\avd
doesn't exist so instead 
go to this path --> C:\Users\.android and right click on this folder and uncheck the box having name as read only.

Hope this helps those with newer windows on their pc :) , if this solution helps you than please vote for it.

Answer (score 2):

In my case i have mistake with the slash.
while specifying "Additional Emulator Command Line Options" in eclipse

Actually it should be -sdcard C:/Kamal/sdcard/emulator_sdcard

and i was putting -sdcard C:\Kamal\sdcard\emulator_sdcard

Then after restarting the Eclipse & Emulator it works.

Answer (score 2):

If the data in the sd card is not updated in the emulator or in the app which you are developing then,
Select,
Dev Tools->Media Scanner
The data which has been already pushed into the sd card by variant means will get loaded soon.!

Answer (score 2):

if some one have same problem in new build of studio . 0.8.9 and above see my solution here and it will work like a charm : (afra mehrparvar solution in the bottom of the page )

[Android Emulator sdcard push error: Read-only file system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2083709/android-emulator-sdcard-push-error-read-only-file-system/26676631#26676631)