# Cannot store images in android emulator

Tags: android

I have tried to push the images in file explorer, but the image does not show up in gallery.

What do I have to do ? What is dev tools ? Do I have to do something with that?

```
Failed to push selection: Read-only file system
```

Comment: after pushing image in fileexplore..,restart your emulator ..

Comment: Failed to push selection: Read-only file system

Comment: see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2083709/android-emulator-sdcard-push-error-read-only-file-system

Comment: see thi http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11144916/eclipse-console-showsfailed-to-push-selection-read-only-file-systemwhen-i-tr

Answer (score 1):

What you can do,

When your emulator active at that time you need to push your file or image from directory to your ***file explorer*** or in SD card in DDMS folder.

After that you have to need restart your emulator again.

***Read-only file system***

This is because you haven't given SD Card size when you have create AVD. So edit your AVD and give SD card size to 512.

***UPDATE:***

Use this one.

```
C:\Documents and Settings\<adminstrator>\.android\avd // If this path is not available then you can file your .android file in your C: drive with Admin.
```

take 'properties' of your avd folder (there is a folder for each of the avd's)

```
uncheck 'Read only' -> OK
```

Further you can go with this links.

http://selvaiyyamperumal.blogspot.in/2012/01/failed-to-push-selection-read-only-file.html
https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/9519/how-to-solve-failed-to-push-selection-out-of-memory

Comment: I already set the sd_card size
[2014-03-05 15:18:40 - ddms] transfer error: Read-only file system
[2014-03-05 15:18:40] Failed to push selection: Read-only file system

Comment: Have you created AVD with SD card size?

Comment: there is no C:\Documents and Settings\<adminstrator>\.android\avd
in windows 7

Comment: Check this one C:\Users\admin\.android